# Mongoose: Find all documents with array field which is included in another array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, api, mongoose

So the example for this would be something like this:

Requesting to do a search on the following array:

```
    ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'mango']
```

As for my database, I have a `Recipe` collection which contains a field `ingredints` - being an Array.

Document #1:

`...
ingredients: ['banana', 'apple']
...`

Document #2:

`...
ingredients: ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
...`

Document #3:

`...
ingredients: ['apple', 'orange', 'kiwi']
...`

The output of the query should return Document #1 and Document #2. (Document #3 containing kiwi which is not included in the initial array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            matchingElements: { $setIntersection: [ ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'mango'], "$ingredients" ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $redact: {
            $cond: {
                if: { $eq: [ { $size: "$ingredients" }, { $size: "$matchingElements" } ] },
                then: "$$KEEP",
                else: "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            matchingElements: 0
        }
    }
])
```

[$setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) will give you all the items from `ingredients` that are present in your array. Then you can use [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) to check if `matchingElements` has the same size as `ingredients` which means that all elements match.

Comment: Seems clear. But what if ingredients field is actually an array of objects - example:

ingredients: [{
  ..
  name: 'apple'
  ..
}, {
  ..
  name: 'orange'
  ..
}]

How should the $setIntersection be written now?

Comment: @Gusti you can replace `$ingredients` from first stage with `{ $map: { input: "$ingredients", as: "ingredient", in: "$$ingredient.name" } }` for object which just takes name field and creates new array